# undefined method `collection_check_boxes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, formtastic

I'm trying to make an invoicing app. The form to create an invoice should include a collection of check boxes so the user can choose which lessons to invoice, but I'm getting this error: `undefined method 'collection_check_boxes'`.

Here are the models involved:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lesson_time, :lesson_date, :invoice_id
  belongs_to :invoice
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :due_date
  has_many :lessons
end
```

And the view:

```
<%= form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
    <fieldset>     
        <%= f.label :lessons %>   
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:lessons, Lesson.all, :id, :lesson_date) %>         
    <%= f.submit %>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

collection_check_boxes is not a method of form_builder. Either put:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:lessons, Lesson.all, :id, :lesson_date) %>
```

This will generate html which won't associate with your model (you won't be able to use `MyModel.new(params[my_model]`) and expect to get proper response. You would either have to manually call my_model.lessons = params[:lessons] or you can pass a html name parameter to conform your check box name to rails convention).

Or, if you are using [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) as you tagged it, you can use this:

```
<%= f.input :lessons, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Lesson.all %>
```

Comment: The Formtastic input method works! Thanks! So collection_check_boxes is a Rails helper but not a form_builder method? Form_builder has no way to handle collections of check boxes? That seems strange since collection_select is a form_builder method.

Comment: Yes, you cannot call collection_check_boxes on regular builder. You have a method called f.check_box which can take multiple option as a parameter, but you would have to iterate through the collection. Yes, but you should have in mind that html select is intended to have multiple values and check box is not.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that since you tagged your post ruby-on-rails-3, you might be trying to use a rails 4 method inside a rails 3 project.

http://makandracards.com/makandra/32147-rails-4-introduced-collection_check_boxes

You'll likely need to use good old `check_box_tag` instead.