# collection_check_boxes is not working throwing undefined method error (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two controller one is `project_controller.rb` and another one is `service_controller.rb`. So I want to store `services_ids` into the `project`.

codes of `project_controller.rb`

```
def get_service_list
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

codes of `project.rb` model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :services_ids, :user_id, :vendor_id
  has_many :services
end
```

codes of `service.rb` Model

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :vendor_id
  belongs_to :project
end
```

codes of `get_service_list.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :services_ids, Service.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But its throwing this error `undefined method collection_check_boxes for` `#<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x9e996d0>`

I followed [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140274/undefined-method-collection-check-boxes) and [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box) links

***Full error Stack***

```
NoMethodError in Projects#get_service_list

Showing /home/test/ROR/vms/app/views/projects/get_service_list.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `collection_check_boxes' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xacdc9b8>

Extracted source (around line #5):

2: 
3:    
4:    <!-- %= collection_check_boxes(:projects, :services_ids,Service.all, :id, :name) % -->
5:    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :projects, :services_ids, Service.all, :id, :name_with_initial %>
6:    
7:    <%= f.submit %>
8: 

Rails.root: /home/test/ROR/vms
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/projects/get_service_list.html.erb:5:in `block in _app_views_projects_get_service_list_html_erb___693653039_90594350'
app/views/projects/get_service_list.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_projects_get_service_list_html_erb___693653039_90594350'
```

Please help.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your `project_controller code` and `service model attributes`.

Comment: @Pavan .. I have updated the question. Please help

Comment: Did you tried like this without f `<%= collection_check_boxes(:projects, :services_ids,Service.all, :id, :name) %>`?

Comment: no actually I am using form_for. So I did't tried that

Comment: Try giving like that.

Comment: Ya tried just now .. Its showing the same error `undefined method collection_check_boxes`

Comment: Post your full error stack.

Comment: Try giving `form_for` as `<%= form_for @project do |f| %>`

Comment: no @Pavan.. Same error

Comment: Ok One last.Change this `@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])` to `@project = Project.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: No No `:project_id` is different , I mentioned it in `routes.rb`

Comment: No.. getting the same error again

Comment: I believe you are using rails 3, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is because you are using** `Rails 3`.

[`collection_check_boxes_tag`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) was [introduced in Rails 4](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes). For your current use, you will **have to** iterate over your collection `Service.all` and make a checkbox for each object as:

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <% for service in Service.find(:all) %>
    <%= check_box_tag "project[services_ids][]", service.id %>
    <%= service.name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You can also refer a brilliant RailsCast by Ryan Bates [for Checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes).

Comment: No problem :) Glad that it got you sorted.